# How do I force a Join query in a ManyToOne relationship using Spring Boot and Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I've madeup a very simple project with a Title table (Mr, Mrs etc) and a Student table, which has a ManyToOne relationship to Title.

When I find all students, Hibernate issues one query for the list of students, then a separate query for each title. I was expecting it to do all this in a single query with a join.

I was hoping spring would handle this, without having to resort to writing my own queries for such a simple case.

Here is my setup:

```
@Entity(name = "title")
@Data
public class Title {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "TITLE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long titleId;

    @Column(name = "SHORT_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String shortName;
}

@Entity(name = "student")
@Data
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long studentId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TITLE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Title title;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;
}

public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {
}

@RestController
public class JoinController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/student")
    public String allStudents() {
        Iterable<Student> students = repository.findAll();
        return "students: " + students;
    }
}
```

Here is the output, showing all (4) queries:

```
org.hibernate.SQL             :logStatement[109] 
    select
        student0_.student_id as student_1_0_,
        student0_.name as name2_0_,
        student0_.title_id as title_id3_0_ 
    from
        student student0_
org.hibernate.SQL             :logStatement[109] 
    select
        title0_.title_id as title_id1_1_0_,
        title0_.short_name as short_na2_1_0_ 
    from
        title title0_ 
    where
        title0_.title_id=?
o.h.t.d.sql.BasicBinder       :bind[81] binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
org.hibernate.SQL             :logStatement[109] 
    select
        title0_.title_id as title_id1_1_0_,
        title0_.short_name as short_na2_1_0_ 
    from
        title title0_ 
    where
        title0_.title_id=?
o.h.t.d.sql.BasicBinder       :bind[81] binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [2]
org.hibernate.SQL             :logStatement[109] 
    select
        title0_.title_id as title_id1_1_0_,
        title0_.short_name as short_na2_1_0_ 
    from
        title title0_ 
    where
        title0_.title_id=?
o.h.t.d.sql.BasicBinder       :bind[81] binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [3]
```

Also, table setup for Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE TITLE (
  TITLE_ID   BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  SHORT_NAME TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
  STUDENT_ID BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  TITLE_ID   BIGSERIAL,
  NAME       TEXT NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE STUDENT ADD FOREIGN KEY (TITLE_ID) REFERENCES TITLE;

INSERT INTO TITLE (TITLE_ID, SHORT_NAME) VALUES (1, 'Mr');
INSERT INTO TITLE (TITLE_ID, SHORT_NAME) VALUES (2, 'Mrs');
INSERT INTO TITLE (TITLE_ID, SHORT_NAME) VALUES (3, 'Dr');

INSERT INTO STUDENT (STUDENT_ID, TITLE_ID, NAME) VALUES (1, 1, 'Smith');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (STUDENT_ID, TITLE_ID, NAME) VALUES (2, 1, 'Anderson');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (STUDENT_ID, TITLE_ID, NAME) VALUES (3, 2, 'Jones');
INSERT INTO STUDENT (STUDENT_ID, TITLE_ID, NAME) VALUES (4, 3, 'Livingston');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a new method in your repository say `findAllStudentsAlongWithTitle` and specify the HQL Join query using `@Query` annotation on top of it. You can find sample `@Query` that uses `JOIN` [here](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/spring-data-jpa-repository.html)

**UPDATE:**

I tried the code and I see the same behavior i.e., multiple queries getting fired irrespective of `fetch` attribute or `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` as fetch strategy.

The reason being the `findAll` internally creates `JPQL` query, say, `(from Student s)` as uses it get the data. And by default `JPQL` does not consider the `fetch strategy` configured in the entity mapping and default strategy is `SELECT`. So this results in fetching the parent first (i.e., Student) and then subsequently loads the children (Title) in the subsequent queries (i.e., 1+3 queries). You can notice the same behavior when using the `JPQL` query directly using `em.createQuery(...).getResultList()`.

On a different note, I have tested the same with `findOne` method that takes `id` as an argument with the `StudentRepository`. It actually resulted in fetching both student and title with a single `JOIN`, unless we mark it explicitly to lazy load with `fetch=LAZY`. This, most likely, is because the `findOne` method does not use `JPQL` and instead uses `em.find(...)`, that respects the `fetch or @Fetch` configured in the entity mapping, and for `EAGER` associations it uses a `JOIN` as default strategy. You can notice the same behavior while using the `em.find(...)` directly.

Comment: I've already tried `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` but it makes no difference.


I was hoping that Spring/Hibernate would handle such a simple example, without having to resort to writing queries myself.

Comment: @Rob You are right. I noticed the same behavior with your code and I think this is expected. I have updated my answer with the reason why it is an expected behavior. Please have a look. Hope that answers.